# PySpark write DataFrame long duration after many custom computation layers

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am having performance issues when trying to write the resultant `master_df` from the following general script. I've attached the whole script as an MCVE, for completeness' sake. In general there's just a ton of custom computation being doing over many millions of rows. The calculations are correct, but I can't get `master_df` to write in any reasonable time. Does anyone have any tips on strategies for improving the performance of this pipeline?

`performance_debug_example.py`:

```
'''
spark-submit \
    --master yarn \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --conf spark.pyspark.driver.python=/hadoop/opt/python_anaconda/3-5.1.0/bin/python \
    --conf spark.pyspark.python=/hadoop/opt/python_anaconda/3-5.1.0/bin/python \
    --conf spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles=true \
    --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.HADOOP_USER_NAME=name \
    --num-executors 20 \
    --executor-memory 30G \
    --driver-memory 15G \
    performance_debug_example.py
'''

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import Row
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql.types import *

import random
import datetime

# Attempt to replicate `pandas.get_dummies` for PySpark
def get_dummies(column, df, incl_levels=None, excl_levels=None, to_str=True):
    '''
    Attempt to replicate pandas' `get_dummies` functionality.
    Don't try this at home, kids... This could be a bad idea with
    many high-cardinality columns.
    '''
    # All possible values in `column`
    categories = df.select(column).distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
    # Option to coerce to str
    categories = [str(cat) if to_str else cat for cat in categories]
    # Limit discrete levels, if desired
    if incl_levels:
        categories = [c for c in categories if c in incl_levels]
    if excl_levels:
        categories = [c for c in categories if c not in excl_levels]
    # One-hot-encode
    categories.sort()
    new_columns = []
    for category in categories:
        encode = func.udf(lambda item: 1 if item == category else 0, IntegerType())
        new_column = '{}_{}'.format(column, category)
        df = df.withColumn(new_column, encode(func.col(column)))
        new_columns.append(new_column)
    return df, new_columns

########## Begin setup of massive DataFrame ##########
########## Nothing really to see here ################
categorical_columns = {'categorical_{}'.format(letter) for letter in 'abcdef'}
continuous_columns = {'continuous_{}'.format(letter) for letter in 'abcdef'}

row_maker = Row(*(list(categorical_columns) + list(continuous_columns) + ['start_timestamp']))

categorical_values = set('abcdefgh')
continuous_values = set(range(1000))

data = []
for idx in range(100000000):
    row_categorical_values = {col: random.sample(categorical_values, 1)[0] for col in categorical_columns}
    row_continuous_values = {col: random.sample(continuous_values, 1)[0] for col in continuous_columns}
    row = row_maker(*(list(row_categorical_values.values()) + list(row_continuous_values.values()) + [datetime.datetime.utcnow()]))
    data.append(row)

sc = SparkContext()

df = (
    sc.parallelize(data)
    .toDF()
    .withColumn('start_timestamp', func.col('start_timestamp').cast('timestamp').alias('start_timestamp'))
)

df = df.withColumn('start_window', func.window('start_timestamp', '30 minutes'))
########## End setup of massive DataFrame ##########

########## Begin encoding features ##########
strategies = {col: ['mean', 'sum'] for col in continuous_columns | categorical_columns}

results = {}
for col, strategy_config in strategies.items():
    if col in categorical_columns:
        df, new_columns = get_dummies(col, df)
    else:
        new_columns = [col]
    gb = df.groupBy('start_window')
    for new_column in new_columns:
        for s in strategy_config:
            new_col = '{}_{}'.format(s, new_column)
            result = gb.sum(new_column) if s == 'sum' else gb.mean(new_column) if s == 'mean' else None
            results[new_col] = result

for i, (column, result_df) in enumerate(results.items()):
    if i == 0:
        master_df = result_df
    else:
        master_df = master_df.join(result_df, 'start_window', 'inner')

master_df.write.mode('overwrite').format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option('header', 'true').save('/tenant/x/performance_debug')
```

Comment: There is lots of stuff going on in this code and I don't believe that it's fit for SO. But for my own curiosity, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: It's probably not, since I'm asking about optimization of already-working code. I would have posted it to Code Review, but the odds of getting something useful there versus here were slim... Anyway, I'm basically doing a few transformations on a very large dataset (100,000,000 records), [one-hot encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) categorical predictors, and then doing some aggregation and math (e.g. the average value for *x* over a given time interval) for many columns. I think the issue comes from the sheer amount of layers of computation added. This takes 3.5 hrs to sv to disk

Comment: You need to try isolating the bits that are taking to much time. Separate concerns first. Data generation per example. (Btw that task isn’t optimized at all, you ought using pyspark directly to do that instead of writing everything to a list then converting it to a DataFrame.

Comment: Right. I've provided the full code for an MCVE so those interested in helping could tag along. I'm still digging into the Spark UI for details as to where this hangs, but I'm relatively new to Spark which is why I'm here. I think my question is pretty clear, per the title. The problem is with the final step -- everything else is demonstrating how I got there.

Comment: The data generation is provided just for the purposes of this example. In reality I'm just reading a ton of CSVs from HDFS, but I can't provide that data here, so that step is literally just a set-up very similar to the DataFrame I'm actually using. That step is a non-issue.

Comment: Let's continue our conversation here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127924/apache-spark